# Як позбутися неоднозначності при використанні перехідного відмінку?

Tags: відмінювання, іменники, керування-відмінками

Перехідний (перетворювальний) відмінок іменників ([Translative case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translative_case)) — це майже зниклий відмінок, який позначає, що деякий предмет (позначений іменником чи займенником) перетворюється на щось інше.
Наприклад:

- *Опівночі карета перетворюється **на гарбуза***;
- *[Кандидат](http://sum.in.ua/s/kandydat) **на посаду голови́** правління*;
- але також *кандидат **у го́лови** правління*;
- *Кандидат **у майстри** спорту*, *кандидат **у депутати***;
- *Коли я виросту, піду **у космонавти***;
- також, *балотуватися **на депутата*** і *балотуватися **у депутати***.

Наведені приклади демонструють два варіанти формування подібних іменників:

1. *у* + форма, схожа на множину;
2. *на* + родовий або знахідний відмінок.

Отже, запитання: чому існують дві різні форми, і яке правило використання тієї чи іншої форми?

Comment: Здається, що в тій формі скрізь форма, яка тотожна родовому/знахідному відмінку. Не забувайте, що _піду **коні** напувать_ – це теж знахідний відмінок, а не називний, така сама форма, як _у голови, у космонавти, у депутати_.

Comment: @YellowSky, дякую, слушно. Я відчуваю, що десь упускаю якийсь важливий аспект, але поки що не знаю, який саме; тому і запитав. Можливо, хтось оформить у вигляді відповіді.

Answer (score 1):

Варіанти бачу таким чином:

- *на гарбуз*, *на посаду, на депутата* — однина
- *у го́лови, у майстри́, у депутати* — множина

Тобто балотуватися *на когось* (одного), балотуватися *у когось* (долучатися до когорти багатьох таких же).

Comment: Знов-таки, посилання є дуже важливими. Ми не знаємо і не розуміємо причин, чому конкретний користувач бачить проблему тим чи іншим чином. Натомість, поважні джерела не лише надають більше подробиць до відповіді, але вони також формують контекст, який дозволяє зрозуміти проблему цілком.

Comment: Чи тут потрібні поважні джерела, щоб вказати, де однина, де множина?
Звісно, дам посилання, якщо знайду роботу, де буде це сказано.

Comment: Так, ви маєте довести, що це саме множина. Я, наприклад, вважаю, що це рештки транслативного відмінку, який лише схожий на множину. І саме для того, щоб у коментарях не виникало хвилі спростувань і заперечень, потрібні джерела. Ну, і мінусів зайвих воно позбавляє.

Comment: Тоді дайте, будь ласка, джерело на те, що транслативний відмінок в українській мові справді був.